# Mod rewrite for subfolder in subfolder

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdirectory

this is my file structure at the web server:

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT/
  foo/
    www/
    .htaccess
  bar/
  index.php
```

What i should write to `foo/.htaccess`, if I want to redirect everything from `www.myserver.com/foo/www/` to `www.myserver.com/foo/`?

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L,NE]
```

But error 404 is always shown. I tried elaborate with RewriteBase also with no success.

Thanks a lot

P.S. When `www/` and `.htaccess` is in DOCUMENT_ROOT, it works OK. But when I put them to subfolder, always getting error 404 :-(

Comment: So you want to go to `http://www.myserver.com/foo/` and get served the stuff in `/foo/www`?

Comment: `RewriteBase /foo/` didn't worked ?

Comment: Yes, I want to go to `http://www.myserver.com/foo/` and get served the stuff in `/foo/www`.

Comment: No, `RewriteBase /foo/` didn't work. I tried it on the web server, and on my localhost (XAMPP) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, I want to go to `http://www.myserver.com/foo/` and get served the stuff in `/foo/www`

This will never work if your htaccess file is in `/foo/www` because it won't take effect unless the request is for something inside `/foo/www`. The request is only `/foo` so the `.htaccess` file is ignored. You'll need to either move the `.htaccess` file to the document root, changing it to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/www
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /foo/www/$1 [L]
```

or move it to the `/foo` directory, changing it to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [L]
```